# Trouble adding variables in PHP Form

Tags: javascript, php, contact-form

I'm completely new to PHP so apologies if this is a very obvious question. The problem I have is that I would like to create a form that collects a few extra details than the traditional "name" "email" and "message".

Specifically, I'd like to have the following labels;

(i) Will you be attending 
(ii) Your Name 
(iii) Your Email
(iv) Your Guests Name
(v) Message

Here's what I have so far

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>

<div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label>Attendance</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Will you be attending?" id="going" required data-validation-required-message="Please type [Yes] or [No]">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label>Your Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label>Email Address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label>Your Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your guests name" id="guest" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your guests name. Type 'none' if none.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls" id="message">
                                <label>Any dietary requirements</label>
                                <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Have you any dietary requirements?" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div id="success"></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark">SEND YOUR REPLY</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

and the PHP

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$guestname = $_POST['guestname'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

and the JS

```
$(function() {

$("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
        // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
        // get values from FORM
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var phone = $("input#phone").val();
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();
        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
        // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
        if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "contact_me.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: name,
                phone: phone,
                email: email,
                message: message
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                // Success message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-    success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button     type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-    hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append('</div>');

                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            error: function() {
                // Fail message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " +      firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
        })
    },
    filter: function() {
        return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
});

$("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab("show");
});
```

});

```
/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
$('#success').html('');
});
```

When I submit the form, I receive information for name, email and message - but I'm missing details for 'guest name' and 'will you be attending'

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please show us your form.

Comment: @Script47 please see my edit which included the form

Comment: Where is your `action` and `method` property?

Comment: @Script47 I'm using Javascript

Comment: Im amazed you are getting any data - your form elements need `name` attributes, eg `name="going"`

Comment: Better edit your question to show the javascript then

Comment: @Steve added javascript :)

Comment: @Jedda added the tags, in the future use the correct tags.

Comment: See the data object in the ajax section of your js code - that's what you are sending to the server. If you need to send other info, it must be added to that data object

Answer (score 0):

I can see at least two obvious mistakes in the code that you submitted to us. Firstly,

```
$guestname = $_POST['guestname']
```

your HTML form input has

```
id="guest"
```

instead of 'guestname'. Change either so that they match.

and your php code is missing the id="going" POST

Therefore it should be:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$guestname = $_POST['guest'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$isAttending = $_POST['going'] /* $isAttending or something along those lines */
```

Answer (score 0):

(You've made a type for the guest name

```
$guestname = $_POST['guest'];
```

Then you didnt show us how you check the "will you be attending, so i guess

```
$attending = $_POST['going'];
```